# how to check if a char is passed as an int

Tags: java

Is it possible to check if a char has been passed into a method that requires an int?
For example, if you have some function foo(int bar) and someone uses that function like foo('t'),
are you able to find out that a char was inputted and not an int?
I know that the char is converted into an int but I am trying to limit anything other than pure integers getting through the function.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Integer instead of int.

```
void foo(Integer bar) { }
```

If you try to invoke foo('A') you will get a compiler error.

Comment: Ah I think that is what I am supposed to implement thanks :D.
And thanks for the sneaky solution Pax, very elegant way of getting around it :)

Comment: Using an Integer instead of int can carry a significant perform overhead of more than 10x

Comment: You could do this temporarily, check your code still compiles and revert the change when it does.

Comment: Don't use it if you're writing applications for constrained devices and if a fraction of a second delay concerns you a lot.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's impossible because Java itself upgrades the `char` to an `int` if it can.

You could make an overload of your function that takes a `char` parameter instead of an `int` which might throw an exception, but that won't stop anyone from casting the `char` to an `int` and calling the `int` version.

There is absolutely no difference at all between the character constant `'A'` cast to an integer and the integer 65, so it would be completely impossible to distinguish the cases.

**Update from Pax:**

I would argue that explicit casting is NOT passing a `char`, it's the caller converting a `char` to an `int` then passing the `int`. This solution catches the inadvertent passing of a `char`.

Pinching someone's code from another answer, that would be:

```
public class Test {
    private static void someMethod(char c) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("I don't think so, matey!");
    }
    private static void someMethod(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        someMethod(100);
        someMethod('d');
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: I don't think so, matey!
    at Test.someMethod(Test.java:4)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. I didn't think there was a way to distinguish between them.

Cheers

Comment: But you could argue that explicit casting is NOT passing a char, it's the caller converting a char to an int then passing the int. The overloaded function should catch the other (a sneaky solution, by the way, so I'm upvoting you).

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to limit anything other
>   than pure integers getting through the
>   function.

You're having a little bit of a conceptual mismatch with Java. A `char` in Java is just a number; the fact that you use the type `char` instead of the type `int` is because you want a number that is 16 bits instead of 32 bits.

A `char` is just a number that goes from 0 to 65535. An `int` is just a number that goes from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Now, I understand that you want to prevent people from calling your method with nonsensical things like `foo('t')`. However, as soon as your program is compiled, Java actually transforms this call to `foo(116)`.

In effect, someone calling your method with a character as the parameter is as silly as calling your method with an arbitrary number. If you are stuck in such a situation, consider these possibilities:

- Do some characters yield an invalid input to your method?

  *For example, you want a brightness value between 0 and 255, and `setBrightness('Δ')` is actually `setBrightness(916)`.*

  Throw an exception - you should be doing this anyway!
- Do you want a character representing a numerical value to be parsed?

  *For example, you want a brightness value between 0 and 9, and `setBrightness('5')` should actually be `setBrightness(5)`.*

  Parse the character as a String.

_

```
char a = '5';
String a_s = String.valueOf(a);
int a_i = Integer.parseInt(a_s);
setBrightness(a_i)
```

- Does the method do everything properly, but passing a character as a parameter is silly?

  *For example, you want a brightness value between 0 and 1,000,000, and `setBrightness('q')` just rubs you the wrong way.*

  Leave it alone. Calling `setBrightness('q')` is bad form, but that's the problem of the other coder. Don't do it yourself though! You'll kick yourself later when you're digging through a Unicode table trying to figure out what you meant at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The casting of `char` to `int` will occur at compile-time, so it won't be possible to determine whether a `char` was passed in, or an `int` was passed in.

In order to illustrate, let's examine the source code and the resulting bytecode of a program which has a `someMethod(int)` which is called by passing an `char` and `int`:

Source code:

```
class CharIntCast
{
    private static void someMethod(int i)
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        someMethod(100);
        someMethod('d');
    }
}
```

Bytecode:

```
Compiled from "CharIntCast.java"
class CharIntCast extends java.lang.Object{
CharIntCast();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

private static void someMethod(int);
  Code:
   0:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   bipush  100
   2:   invokestatic    #2; //Method someMethod:(I)V
   5:   bipush  100
   7:   invokestatic    #2; //Method someMethod:(I)V
   10:  return

}
```

As can be seen in the bytecode, both the values `100` and `'d'` are already handled as an integer when it is pushed onto the stack by the `bipush` instruction before making a call to the `someMethod`.

Therefore, at runtime, it won't be possible to find out whether the method argument was either an `int` or `char`, as the casting is performed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your integers are confined to a range that is outside the range of a char, then you cannot do this since you cannot tell whether a value 64 is an int or a char.